# List comprehension when there are repeated elements in both lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to find all words that have a particular set of target letters. My code works when none of the letters in the target is repeated, but not if there are repeats.

Here is my code:

```py
target = 'bba'
target_words = [
  'aani', 'aaru', 'abac', 'abas', 
  'abba', 'abby', 'abed', 'abel', 'abet'
]
target_list = list(target)


final_list = []
for word in target_words:
    word_list = list(word)
    if (all(x in word_list for x in target_list)):
        final_list.append(word)
        
print('Final list: ', final_list)
```

The output is `Final list:  ['abac', 'abas', 'abba', 'abby', 'abed', 'abel', 'abet']`

I would like it to be `Final list:  ['abba', 'abby']`

I cannot find a way to get the result I want. It may be because I am converting the letters of the words into a list, but I don't see how to do it otherwise.

Comment: How should it handle `abbb`?   That has your targets but should the extra `b` disqualify it?   That has relevance to @BrokenBenchmark s answer

Comment: As an aside, why are you doing `target_list = list(target)`? Why not just use `target`? Similarly, `word_list = list(word)`... you could have just do `all(x in word for x in target_list)` no need to create pointless, intermediate lists.

Comment: @JLPeyret It should indeed handle `abbb` correctly; that is, the extra `b` is allowed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The honest answer is because I am still very new to Python and have not yet fully grasped many of the subtleties. To my mind, if I want to see whether a bunch of letters is present, in any order, in a bunch of other letters, I need to consider each letter as a thing.

Comment: @jcherfas a string is a sequence of individual letters. See what happens if you do `data = "abc"` then `print(data[0])` or  `for c in data: print(c)`

Comment: Of course you are right, and I know that because I do use `len(data)` but I had not fully internalised that yet. `data.split()` also makes that clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for `collections.Counter()`. It gives us a clean way to check whether the desired overlap exists between a word in `target_words` and the `target`, accounting for duplicate letters (with a suggested improvement by [azro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7212686/azro)):

```py
from collections import Counter

target_counter = Counter(target)
[word for word in target_words if Counter(word) & target_counter == target_counter]
```

This outputs:

```py
['abba', 'abby']
```

Comment: `Counter(target)` could be built once for all, not 2 times per word of list

Comment: Edited into original answer (with attribution). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: In Python 3.10 +, you can just do `Counter(word) >= target_counter` instead of `Counter(word) & target_counter == target_counter`

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Thank you very much for your solution and for introducing me to `collections.Counter()`. I can see that I could find a use for this approach in other things I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First let's find the unique letters in your target word.

```
target_word_letters = set(target)
```

Now, we can use a dictionary comprehension to get a count of each letter.

```
counts = {letter: target.count(letter) for letter in target_word_letters}
```

Now we need a list comprehension that iterates over `target_words` and checks that for every letter in `counts`, the same number (or more) of that letter is in the target word.

```
[word for word in target_words if all(word.count(l) >= c for l, c in counts.items())]
```

Result:

```
['abba', 'abby']
```