# What exactly is the bitwise AND doing with collections.Counter?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

There was a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72263877) where the, correct, answer really surprised me by using `&` on two Counters and then "getting it right".

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Counters support rich comparison operators for equality, subset, and superset relationships: ==, !=, <, <=, >, >=. All of those tests treat missing elements as having zero counts so that Counter(a=1) == Counter(a=1, b=0) returns true.

But that doesn't go into the specifics of `&`.  I wrote a small test script:

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pp

cls = Counter  # `dict` fails: TypeError: unsupported operand type

o1 = cls(a=1,b=2,c=3,de=3,f=3,i1=9)
o2 = cls(a=1,b=2,c=3,de=5,f=6,i2=9)
res = o1 & o2

pp(dict(o1=o1,o2=o2,res=res))
```

##### the output is:

```
{'o1': Counter({'i1': 9, 'c': 3, 'de': 3, 'f': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}),
 'o2': Counter({'i2': 9, 'f': 6, 'de': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}),
 'res': Counter({'c': 3, 'de': 3, 'f': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1})}
```

It seems to me that `counter1 & counter2` means:

- calculate the intersection of the keys of both.
- for the values on common keys, compute the `min`

Am I correct?   Asides from `Counter`, and `set`, do any other standard library data structures also define `__and__` (the backing dunder for `&`, IIRC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is pretty much correct. [If you look a couple lines down from where you've quoted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you'll see an example use of `&` on `Counter` objects -- you don't need to dive into the source code to find it:

> Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. ...
>
> ```py
> >>> c & d                       # intersection:  min(c[x], d[x])
> Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})
> >>> c | d                       # union:  max(c[x], d[x])
> Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2})
> ```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that intersection would take the minimum? Does the ordering of the operands matter? `c1 & c2` vs `c2 & c1`? In other words, I would think it just accepts the first (or last) key, not necessarily the min/max

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your question. The docs say that intersection produces the minimum value, so there isn't any reason to assume otherwise.

Comment: I understand what the docs say, but there are two different ways to implement an intersection - either the left side stays, or it is overridden by the right side. A union, alternatively will always insert all right side elements into the left. I'm just surprised that it _always_ compares the values of the keys

Comment: I'd guess that it's because `Counter` objects have to deal with weird edge cases involving zero frequencies. You can create a `Counter` with a zero frequency for a key if you want, but if I create a `Counter` from an iterable, keys that don't appear in the iterable won't appear in the `Counter`. I didn't write the code for this though, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Intersection is what's in *both*. If one has a certain value three times and the other has it five times, then both have it three times. Why would order matter for that?

Comment: @KellyBundy A counter cannot have duplicate keys, so what do you mean "three / five times"? The keys are what are being overridden, when intersecting.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Think of them as multisets, as the documentation also says.

Comment: @OneCricketeer E.g., `Counter({42: 3})` represents the multiset {42,42,42}.

Answer (score 1):

Container [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) state:

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. **Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts.** Equality and inclusion compare corresponding counts. Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less.

To address your question about other dict derivatives overriding `&`, I don't believe so. However, `set` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) here) uses `&`, `|`, `-` and `^` to implement intersection, union, difference and symmetric difference.

Comment: Yeah, edited the question a bit (no need to alter your answer) to show I was aware of `set` using `&`.  I guess I was just surprised to see that operator defined on Counter, although it does "make sense".

Answer (score 0):

Per [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> ```
> >>> c = Counter(a=3, b=1)
> >>> d = Counter(a=1, b=2)
> >>> c + d                       # add two counters together:  c[x] + d[x]
> Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3})
> >>> c - d                       # subtract (keeping only positive counts)
> Counter({'a': 2})
> >>> c & d                       # intersection:  min(c[x], d[x])
> Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})
> >>> c | d                       # union:  max(c[x], d[x])
> Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2})
> >>> c == d                      # equality:  c[x] == d[x]
> False
> >>> c <= d                      # inclusion:  c[x] <= d[x]
> False
> ```

Unary operations are also defined:

> ```
> >>> c = Counter(a=2, b=-4)
> >>> +c
> Counter({'a': 2})
> >>> -c
> Counter({'b': 4})
> ```